# Angular 12 data binding problems

Tags: data-binding, binding, angular12

I have a project migrated to angular 12.2 with the **package.json** file configured like this:

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^3.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.8",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.12",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^3.0.2",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "angular2-query-builder": "^0.6.2",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "chart.js": "^3.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.19.0",
    "d3-array": "^3.1.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^5.10.0",
    "geojson": "^0.5.0",
    "gzip-all": "^1.0.0",
    "highcharts": "^9.3.0",
    "jexl": "^2.3.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jsbarcode": "^3.11.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nanoscroller": "^0.8.7",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-localized-numbers": "^0.4.1",
    "ngx-schema-form": "^2.6.6",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^12.2.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "venn.js": "^0.2.20",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.3",
    "z-schema": "^4.2.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.11",
    "@types/angular": "^1.8.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.36",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0"
  }
}
```

The **tsconfig.app.json** file is configured like this:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["googlemaps","jquery","node"]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

The **tsconfig.json** file is configured like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2018","dom"],
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    //"enableIvy": false,
    "strictDomEventTypes": false
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, no data binding is done on any variable of any view, why?
I am using the same configuration on an angular 10 project and everything works fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At this time I solved it like this:

- example I replaced `{{variable}}` with `<span [innerText]="variable"></span>`

However I didn't understand why I can't use `{{variable}}` syntax ... I hope someone can help me.

Thanks.